# Mongoose/Typescript issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

So, i have to update some data inside my main interface, the problem is that, when i tried to do that, it complains because `.save()` is not defined

So i create another interface to that data in order to `extends Document` so i can have access to .save()

But, here's the new error....

```
const theComment: IComment
Type 'Comment' is missing the following properties from type 'IComment': $getAllSubdocs, $ignore, $isDefault, $isDeleted, and 47 more.
```

Here's my code

What i want to update ( the problem is theComment )

```
export const editComment = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  const {publicationId} = req.params;

  const { identifier, body, commentId } = req.body;

  // Check id's

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(identifier!))
    return res.status(400).json({ Message: "identifier not valid" });

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(publicationId!))
    return res.status(400).json({ Message: "identifier not valid" });

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(commentId!))
    return res.status(400).json({ Message: "identifier not valid" });
  
  // Find pub

  const thePub: Ipub = await Publication.findById(publicationId);

  // Find user

  const theUser: Iauth = await User.findById(identifier);

  // Find comment, make sure that comment is from that user

  const theComment: IComment = thePub.comments!.find((f) => f.id === commentId && f.identifier === theUser.id)!;

  if(!theComment) return res
  .status(405)
  .json({ Message: "You are not the owner of the comment || Comment doesn't exist" })

  // Make sure body is not empty

  if(!body) return res.status(404).json({Message: 'No data provided'})

  try {

    // Update comment and perfil if it has changed

    theComment.body = body;
    theComment.perfil = theUser.perfil;

    await theComment.save()

    return res.json(theComment)

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ Error: "the API failed" });
  }
};
```

Main interface

```
export interface Ipub extends Document {
  id?: string;
  body: string;

  photo: string;

  creator: {
    name: string;
    perfil?: string;
    identifier: string;
  };

  likes?: Likes[];

  comments?: Comment[];

  createdAt: string;
}
```

Data's interface that i want to update inside my main interface

```
export interface IComment extends Document {
  id?: string;
  body: string;
  name: string;
  perfil?: string;
  identifier: string;
  createdAt: string;
  likesComments?: Likes[];
}
```

What can i do ? how can i solve it ?

Thanks for your time comunnity !!

Answer (score 1):

TS Compiler says the object described by `Comment` interface doesn't have `.save()` method. And as far as I presume it should not have because it's not a MongoDB document.

The time you inherit all props from `Document` interface the compiler throws the error saying that types `Comment` & `IComment` are not compatible because the second one has `Document` props, and the first one doesn't. To fix it you should just cast the type directly like this:
`const theComment = thePub.comments!.find((f) => f.id === commentId && f.identifier === theUser.id)! as IComment;`

But in order to update the comment you have to update 'whole' `Publication` document(for example, by using [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)):

```
Publication.update(
  {
    "id": publicationId, 
    "comments.id": commentId,
    "comments.identifier": theUser.id,
  }, 
  { $inc: {
    "comments.$.body": body,
    "comments.$.perfil": theUser.perfil,
  }}, 
  false, 
  true,
);
```

Or the best option I think is to use relationships between Documents. Create another Document named `Comment` and save all related comments there. In that case you will have an ability to use `.save()` and other methods provided.

Comment: Thanks man, that what i did, i save the whole publication with .save() and it worked, but thank you for that aclaration, need to keep working on my typescript skills !